# Can I download Spring Tool Suite for NetBeans?

Tags: java, spring, sts

I need to install Spring Tool Suite (STS) for NetBeans, but I found only Spring Tools for Eclipse on the Spring website.
Can I download Spring Tool Suite for NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

you may use nb-springboot-plugin. you can access it from
https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=4

Comment: Have you been using this plugin in the latest versions of NetBeans? I tried it, faced some problems, mainly with IDE crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Spring does not provide STS for Apache NetBeans. You may try use a custom plugin developed by community.